# Adding more logins on meta sites redirects to 404 pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, per-site-meta

I've seen this behavior on multiple meta sites, for example:

1. [Ask Ubuntu Meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/login-add?returnUrl=/users/current)
2. [Magento SE Meta](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/users/login-add?returnUrl=/users/current)
3. [Meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/login-add?returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent)

As soon as you choose to add a new login (To be honest I only tried Google, Facebook and the OpenId box), you get redirected to a 404 page at [meta site url]/users/authenticate. [Example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate).

In my opinion, since when trying to login (i.e. first time login) on a meta site it redirects to the login page of its main, the "Add more logins" page on meta should also redirect to its main "add more logins" page. I think this would just make it more consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in build 3737 on MSO<sup>†</sup>, and build 2860 on other sites.

<sup>†</sup> The "meta" build is used on both MSO and MSE, but MSE is not a "child meta" and is not affected by this issue.