# "Page Not Found" when trying to add a login on per-site Metas

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, per-site-meta

I experienced a bug in "meta.stackoverflow.com" site.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Visit "MyLogins", for me, it is: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/142239
2. Click "add more logins…", then it redirects to: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/login-add?returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent
3. Try to use any login method on that page, and get redirected to: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate

It says "Page Not Found".

Comment: We should probably redirect back to the main site to add the login. It's not possible to authenticate on a per-site Meta because the session and logins are inherited from the parent site.

Comment: @animuson true, and for the record is was already reported [year and half ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230389/adding-more-logins-on-meta-sites-redirects-to-404-pages)